# How to store Marathi(Indian lang) in MySQL database using JAVA

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to store Marathi(Indian language) in MySQL database. I am getting the data from text box and trying to store it in database.

But, after executing the code, the data is stored like `%^$^^^66` or other special characters which are not in Marathi(Indian language).

I had created database with **utf8_general_ci** collation.

Please help me.

Comment: Since Hindi uses the Devnagri Script like Marathi, see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12435867/how-to-store-the-data-in-unicode-in-hindi-language

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Store hindi words in MYSQL using JAVA web crawler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590713/store-hindi-words-in-mysql-using-java-web-crawler)

Answer (score 0):

If you have database charset is [`utf8`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-unicode-utf8.html) and database collation is `utf8_general_ci` then there should not be any problem.

Check your data which is coming from text box is `unicode` or not.

To verify the database you can simply insert Marathi words directly into the table.

Answer (score 0):

try to change your table structure
ALTER TABLE  MODIFY  CHARACTER SET UTF8;

if table already exist

Comment: Expand on your answer. Write exact SQL commands to apply.